# Porting Java's synchronized() block to C++

Tags: c++, thread-safety, pthreads

I tried to create a class for porting Java's synchronized keyword to C++ using below code using *nix pthread's library.

In general my test cases seem to work, but since this is a very critical topic I would like to have someone else have a look on it in case I missed something which might invalidate my test cases.

The basic idea is that I created a `synchronized(){}` block using a `#define` with help of an `if()` statement (at the very end of the source).

The `synchronized(variableORpointer){}` block uses a variable as a reference OR a pointer and using template functions it finally creates/deletes a mutex and condition variable dynamically for the given address using a pointer to referent OR given pointer.

It also supports Java's notify/notifyAll/wait functions using `Synchronized::notify(variable), Synchronized::notifyAll(variable)` and `Synchronized::wait(variable, timeoutInMs, nanos)` functions.

A null pointer or not holding the lock on calling `wait()` causes an `std::runtime_error` to be thrown.

The most current code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/VRciF/scripts/tree/master/cpp) including a test example.

```
#ifndef __SYNCHRONIZED_HPP__
#define __SYNCHRONIZED_HPP__

#include <pthread.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

class Synchronized{
protected:
    typedef struct metaMutex{
        pthread_mutex_t lock;
        pthread_cond_t cond;

        pthread_t lockOwner;

        int counter;
    } metaMutex;

    pthread_mutex_t& getMutex(){
        static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        return lock;
    }
    std::map<const void*, metaMutex*>& getMutexMap(){
        static std::map<const void*, metaMutex*> mmap;
        return mmap;
    }

    const void *accessPtr;
    metaMutex *metaPtr;
    int dereference;

    template<typename T>
    T * getAccessPtr(T & obj) { return &obj; } //turn reference into pointer!
    template<typename T>
    T * getAccessPtr(T * obj) { return obj; } //obj is already pointer, return it!

public:
    template<typename T>
    Synchronized(const T &ptr, bool lockit=true) : accessPtr(getAccessPtr(ptr)){
        //std::cout << "type: " << typeid(ptr).name() << std::endl;

        if(this->accessPtr==NULL){
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Synchronizing on NULL pointer is not valid, referenced type is: ")+typeid(ptr).name());
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&this->getMutex());

        std::map<const void*, metaMutex*>& mmap = this->getMutexMap();
        std::map<const void*, metaMutex*>::iterator it = mmap.find(this->accessPtr);
        if(it != mmap.end()){
            this->metaPtr = it->second;
            this->metaPtr->counter++;
        }
        else{
            this->metaPtr = new metaMutex();
            pthread_mutex_init(&this->metaPtr->lock, NULL);
            pthread_cond_init(&this->metaPtr->cond, NULL);
            this->metaPtr->counter = 1;
            mmap.insert(std::make_pair(this->accessPtr, this->metaPtr));
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->getMutex());

        if(lockit){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&this->metaPtr->lock);
            this->metaPtr->lockOwner = pthread_self();
        }
    }

    operator int() { return 1; }
    const void* getSynchronizedAddress(){
        return this->accessPtr;
    }

    ~Synchronized(){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->metaPtr->lock);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&this->getMutex());
        metaPtr->counter--;
        if(metaPtr->counter<=0){
            this->getMutexMap().erase(this->accessPtr);
            delete metaPtr;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->getMutex());
    }

    void wait(unsigned long milliseconds=0, unsigned int nanos=0){
        if(pthread_equal(pthread_self(), this->metaPtr->lockOwner)==0){
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("trying to wait is only allowed in the same thread holding the mutex"));
        }

        int rval = 0;
        if(milliseconds == 0 && nanos == 0){
            rval = pthread_cond_wait(&this->metaPtr->cond, &this->metaPtr->lock);
        }
        else{
            struct timespec timeUntilToWait;
            struct timeval now;
            int rt;

            gettimeofday(&now,NULL);

            timeUntilToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec;
            long seconds = 0;
            if(milliseconds >= 1000){
                seconds = (milliseconds/1000);
                milliseconds -= seconds*1000;
            }
            timeUntilToWait.tv_sec += seconds;
            timeUntilToWait.tv_nsec = (now.tv_usec+1000UL*milliseconds)*1000UL + nanos;
            rval = pthread_cond_timedwait(&this->metaPtr->cond, &this->metaPtr->lock, &timeUntilToWait);
        }
        switch(rval){
            case 0:
                this->metaPtr->lockOwner = pthread_self();
                break;
            case EINVAL: throw std::runtime_error("invalid time or condition or mutex given");
            case EPERM: throw std::runtime_error("trying to wait is only allowed in the same thread holding the mutex");
        }
    }
    void notify(){
        if(pthread_cond_signal(&this->metaPtr->cond)!=0){
            std::runtime_error("non initialized condition variable");
        }
    }
    void notifyAll(){
        if(pthread_cond_broadcast(&this->metaPtr->cond)!=0){
            std::runtime_error("non initialized condition variable");
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void wait(const T &ptr, unsigned long milliseconds=0, unsigned int nanos=0){
        Synchronized syncToken(ptr, false);
        syncToken.wait(milliseconds, nanos);
    }
    template<typename T>
    static void notify(const T &ptr){
        Synchronized syncToken(ptr, false);
        syncToken.notify();
    }
    template<typename T>
    static void notifyAll(const T &ptr){
        Synchronized syncToken(ptr, false);
        syncToken.notifyAll();
    }
};

/* from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr */
#define synchronizedTokenPaste(x,y) x ## y
#define synchronizedTokenPaste2(x,y) synchronizedTokenPaste(x,y)
#define synchronized(ptr) if(Synchronized synchronizedTokenPaste2(sync_, __LINE__) = Synchronized(ptr))
#endif
```

Comment: Is C++11 an option?

Comment: Careful with names starting with a double underscore. You see a lot of those in the standard library precisely because they are reserved for library use: http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/1198654

Comment: @Barry in general yes, cause i implemented it this way out of interest and with the best of my (non existing C++11) knowledge - additionally it would be very kind if you might  have a look at my code too regarding possible synchronization flaws in my code since i'm not that much expirienced with condition variables and i'm also a bit unsure about the last lines in the constructor on unlocking/locking might cause a race condition?

Comment: @glampert you mean the define symbol? Thanks for your hint - such detailed standard naming conventions are pretty new to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C++ is not Java**

I cannot stress that enough. You're trying to shoehorn a Java thing into C++, and we end up with macros. Macros are an awful solution to just about every problem and unless you have a compelling reason to use one, don't. This is not a compelling reason. For instance, we could just write:

```
synchronized(container, [&]{
    // stuff
});
```

It's a couple more characters than your solution, while also not having to be a macro. I think that's worth it.

Also, let's use some C++11 features, which are way easier to use with the introductions of `<mutex>` and `<condition_variable>` and `<unordered_map>`.

**`synchronized()`, as a function**

If you wrote it as a function, it would look like:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void synchronized(T const& obj, F&& func)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> outer(SynchroObjects::synchro_mutex);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> inner(_synchro_objects[&obj].mutex);
    std::forward<F>(func)();
}
```

That's it. Sure, I have to show you what `_synchro_objects` is. But this is the power of C++11. We use RAII for locking (no `lock()` or `unlock()`), keep the mutex in a map, and don't need macros. That is super cool.

We just need some other utilities:

```
struct SynchroObjects {
    static std::mutex synchro_mutex;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
};

static std::unordered_map<const void*, SynchroObjects> _synchro_objects;
```

**Other utility functions**

Once we approach things from this perspective, all the other functions just sort of fall into place and are all just a couple lines:

```
template <typename T>
SynchroObjects& getSynchro(T const& container) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(SynchroObjects::synchro_mutex);
    return _synchro_objects[&container];
}

template <typename T>
void notify(T const& container) {
    getSynchro(container).cv.notify_one();
}

template <typename T>
void wait(T const& container) {
    // potentially you could add some safety checking to ensure 
    // that _synchro_objects[&container] exists here, maybe use
    // at() in debug mode or something

    auto& sync = getSynchro(container);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(sync.mutex);
    sync.cv.wait(lk);
}

// wait(T const&, Predicate);
// wait_for(...);
// wait_until(...);
```

Comment: Thats a really awesome example of using many new c++11 features i'm not yet much aware of . Thanks for sharing your enthusiasm on c++11. Regarding your code, am i right that there is a flaw in the synchronized function cause of not locking _synchro_objects itself? So this is meant as c++11-focused example code, right? Could you also elaborate a bit on your first paragraph? Cause the java design pattern on hiding mutex's and focusing on the resource for synchronization is pretty valuable. Thats why i think synchronizing via the resource itself would be great in c++ and/or c++11.

Comment: @JohnDoe Good point, I corrected the flaw. Also, the Java design pattern is valuable but C++ is not Java. In C++, we do C++ things. If you need a specific container synchronized, you should just have a `mutex` along with that container somewhere - don't add this extra outer layer to it.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try to merge this all in some kind of {Synchronized localVar(resource); } way

Comment: _«Macros are an awful solution to just about every problem»_: I dare to vehemently disagree. The only problem with macros is that they have global scope, but then again so do most of the language keywords anyway: you cannot use "const" as the name of a variable, for instance, and that's no different than declaring that _synchronized_ is a new keyword injected in the language by an external library of sorts. The preprocessor *is* part of the language, after all.